# Spring Bean creation by factory methods and Breach of Singleton Pattern

Tags: multithreading, spring, thread-safety, race-condition

Friends, I am reading Spring 3 in Action

And it says :- Spring Containers give Singleton Bean, by default when we create them using Constructors. But if we use a factory method, then it should be implemented in such a way that only single bean is returned. Page Number 37 with heading

```
CREATING BEANS THROUGH FACTORY METHODS
```

Therefore, author had to maintain thread safety by following code. Otherwise there are chances that two concurrent threads may create two instances of Spring Bean.

```
 package com.springinaction.springidol;
  public class Stage {

      private Stage() {
            }

     private static class StageSingletonHolder {

         static Stage instance = new Stage();
              }

       public static Stage getInstance() {
         return StageSingletonHolder.instance;
                }

     }
```

Static getInstance() method returns the same instance every time it’s called. (For thread
safety, getInstance() employs a technique known as “initialization on demand holder” to create the singleton instance.)

Then it uses XML

```
      <bean id="theStage"
        class="com.springinaction.springidol.Stage"
          factory-method="getInstance" />
```

to declare getInstance as the factory method.

Which I understood clearly. But then, out of curiosity, I thought if I remove this thread safe notion from Class Stage by removing this static initialization

```
    package com.springinaction.springidol;
       public class Stage {
       private Stage() {
               }

              public static Stage getInstance() {
               return new Stage();
                 }
          }
```

Then it is possible to have more than one instance of class Stage by two simultaneous threads. I know that this is just a possibility. It would be possible in such a scenario when Thread 1 makes a call to getBean("theStage") method on Spring Container (ApplicationContext) instance. It finds that there is no instance of such bean. In the mean while Thread 2 takes over and it too finds that there is no instance of such bean. Now both threads create the two distinct Spring beans because the factory method is not Thread Safe.

How can this possibility be increased that two threads are returning different instances by modified getInstance method (which is not thread safe now).

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

> How can this possibility be increased that two threads are returning
>   different instances by modified getInstance method (which is not
>   thread safe now)

The only scenario that this will happen is if the bean is using lazy-loading. Otherwise spring will create the bean when is starting up and whenever your threads request an instance of Stage, Spring will return the one that it already has.

I haven't read the book but I guess the author is using the StageSingletonHolder to be 100% sure that the bean will never have another instance in the current classloader. However singletons are a lie in java because you can have more than one class loader and therefore more than one singleton.

This very good article explains this: http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/